# Grouping by an unknown initial prefix

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Say I have the following array of strings as an input:

```
foo-139875913
foo-aeuefhaiu
foo-95hw9ghes
barbazabejgoiagjaegioea
barbaz8gs98ghsgh9es8h
9a8efa098fea0
barbaza98fyae9fghaefag
bazfa90eufa0e9u
bazgeajga8ugae89u
bazguea9guae
aifeaufhiuafhe
```

There are 3 different prefixes used here, "foo-", "barbaz" and "baz" - however these prefixes are not known ahead of time (they could be something completely different).

How could you establish what the different common prefixes are so that they could then be grouped by? This is made a bit tricky since in the data I've provided there's two that start with "bazg" and one that starts "bazf" where of course "baz" is the prefix.

What I've tried so far is sorting them into alphabetical order, and then looping through them in order and counting how many characters in a row are identical to the previous. If the number is different or when 0 characters are identical, it starts a new group. The problem with this is it falls over at the "bazg" and "bazf" problem I mentioned earlier and separates those into two different groups (one with just one element in it)

Edit: Alright, let's throw a few more rules in:

- Longer potential groups should generally be preferred over shorter ones, unless there is a closely matching group of less than X characters difference in length. (So where X is 2, baz would be preferred over bazg)
- A group must have at least Y elements in it or not be a group at all
- It's okay to simply throw away elements that don't match any of the 'groups' to within the rules above.

To clarify the first rule in relation to the second, if X was 0 and Y was 2, then the two 'bazg' entries would be in a group, and the 'bazf' would be thrown away because its on its own.

Comment: How many letters are you considering? You need to decide that. The more letters you consider the more groups you have with less elements on each.

Comment: The prefixes could be any arbitrary length.

Comment: That's obvious. You are really NOT DEFINING A RULE. At which char number I have the prefix?  At which char number I have the word? You need either to define a separator or decide prefix length!
EVEN A HUMAN cannot do this!

Comment: I don't think you really understand the question. As a human, you can look at those and identify which parts are common prefixes. They are completely random and arbitrary but you can pick them out. I want to do the same thing in code.

Comment: This looks like a typical optimization problem. Brute force: From your input, generate the set of all possible solutions. Find the solution with the highest score, where one group with `baz` gets a higher score than two groups with `bazf` and `bazg`. If your input is large for brute force, consider using a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Comment: I think your bazf/bazg problem represents the fact you haven't fully defined what you want. (like if the prefix size isn't fixed, why _aren't_ they separate groups?) You could turn the data in to a tree (branching for each letter), then work out how you actually want to decide on the prefix (maybe having a minimum group size? before allowing a more specific prefix?)

Comment: So you want to minimize the number of groups? Consider all prefixes that start with "a" or "b". You need to understand that there is a tradeoff here between the prefix size and number of groups

Comment: What's to stop a human from decided to group everything beginning with "foo" together, and everything beginning with "ba" together, leaving just two groups? You really, really need to think about this carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's a good question - the answer is of course that we know not to since we can see that there's a pattern. The question should be perhaps about how to make identifying the groups more 'human like' in its behavior.

Comment: @PhonicUK suppose you have: "baa, bab, bba". How many groups are here? One that starts with "b" or two that start with "ba" and "bb"?

Comment: @nmat, too small a sample to decide. In my sample (which isn't entirely atypical of the kind of data it'd get structure wise) there's clearly a number of elements in discrete groups.

Comment: Ok, how large a sample should be?

Comment: I think the example is not very well suited for what you are trying to achieve. From the comments, you can tell that we humans are already arguing about which groups there may be in this small piece of data, let alone "teach" an AI about this.

Comment: @PhonicUK You need to define rules for this. There are *many* ambiguities and the computer won't magically guess what you want.

Comment: @PhonicUK As human, each human will consider this problem in a different way. Example, for me `bazg` is a group with 2 elements and `bazf` is another. That's the difference between HUMAN MIND and MATH. In MATH you have solid edges between groups.

Comment: I've updated the question with a couple of extra rules it can abide by to make it a bit more clear-cut.

Comment: What are the expected groups for the new sample?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici the same, but may change depending on values of X and Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's a quick hack, probably `O(something_bad)`:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<String, IEnumerable<string>>> GuessGroups(IEnumerable<string> source, int minNameLength=0, int minGroupSize=1)
{
    // TODO: error checking
    return InnerGuessGroups(new Stack<string>(source.OrderByDescending(x => x)), minNameLength, minGroupSize);
}

IEnumerable<Tuple<String, IEnumerable<string>>> InnerGuessGroups(Stack<string> source, int minNameLength, int minGroupSize)
{
    if(source.Any())
    {
        var tuple = ExtractTuple(GetBestGroup(source, minNameLength), source);
        if (tuple.Item2.Count() >= minGroupSize)
            yield return tuple;
        foreach (var element in GuessGroups(source, minNameLength, minGroupSize))
            yield return element;   
    }
}

Tuple<String, IEnumerable<string>> ExtractTuple(string prefix, Stack<string> source)
{
    return Tuple.Create(prefix, PopWithPrefix(prefix, source).ToList().AsEnumerable());
}

IEnumerable<string> PopWithPrefix(string prefix, Stack<string> source)
{
    while (source.Any() && source.Peek().StartsWith(prefix))
        yield return source.Pop();
}

string GetBestGroup(IEnumerable<string> source, int minNameLength)
{
    var s = new Stack<string>(source);
    var counter = new DictionaryWithDefault<string, int>(0);
    while(s.Any())
    {
        var g = GetCommonPrefix(s);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(g) && g.Length >= minNameLength)
            counter[g]++;
        s.Pop();
    }
    return counter.OrderBy(c => c.Value).Last().Key;
}

string GetCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> coll)
{
    return (from len in Enumerable.Range(0, coll.Min(s => s.Length)).Reverse()
            let possibleMatch = coll.First().Substring(0, len)
            where coll.All(f => f.StartsWith(possibleMatch))
            select possibleMatch).FirstOrDefault();
}

public class DictionaryWithDefault<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
  TValue _default;
  public TValue DefaultValue {
    get { return _default; }
    set { _default = value; }
  }
  public DictionaryWithDefault() : base() { }
  public DictionaryWithDefault(TValue defaultValue) : base() {
    _default = defaultValue;
  }
  public new TValue this[TKey key]
  {
    get { return base.ContainsKey(key) ? base[key] : _default; }
    set { base[key] = value; }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
string[] input = {
    "foo-139875913",
    "foo-aeuefhaiu",
    "foo-95hw9ghes",
    "barbazabejgoiagjaegioea",
    "barbaz8gs98ghsgh9es8h",
    "barbaza98fyae9fghaefag",
    "bazfa90eufa0e9u",
    "bazgeajga8ugae89u",
    "bazguea9guae",
    "9a8efa098fea0",
    "aifeaufhiuafhe"
};

GuessGroups(input, 3, 2).Dump();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well as discussed, the problem wasn't initially well defined, but here is how I'd go about it.

```
Create a tree T
Parse the list, for each element:
    for each letter in that element
        if a branch labeled with that letter exists then 
            Increment the counter on that branch
            Descend that branch
        else 
            Create a branch labelled with that letter
            Set its counter to 1
            Descend that branch
```

This gives you a tree where each of the leaves represents a word in your input. Each of the non-leaf nodes has a counter representing how many leaves are (eventually) attached to that node. Now you need a formula to weight the length of the prefix (the depth of the node) against the size of the prefix group. For now:

```
S = (a * d) + (b * q) // d = depth, q = quantity, a, b coefficients you'll tweak to get desired behaviour
```

So now you can iterate over each of the non-leaf node and assign them a score S. Then, to work out your groups you would

```
For each non-leaf node
    Assign score S
    Insertion sort the node in to a list, so the head is the highest scoring node

Starting at the root of the tree, traverse the nodes
    If the node is the highest scoring node in the list
        Mark it as a prefix 
        Remove all nodes from the list that are a descendant of it
        Pop itself off the front of the list
        Return up the tree
```

This should give you a list of prefixes. The last part feels like some clever data structures or algorithms could speed it up (the last part of removing all the children feels particularly weak, but if you input size is small, I guess speed isn't too important).

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your requirements aren't off. It seems as if you are looking for a specific grouping size as opposed to specific key size requirements. I have below a program that will, based on a specified group size, break up the strings into the largest possible groups up too, and including the group size specified. So if you specify a group size of 5, then it will group items on the smallest key possible to make a group of size 5. In your example it would group *foo-* as *f* since there is no need to make a more complex key as an identifier.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <remarks><c>true</c> in returned dictionary key are groups over <paramref name="maxGroupSize"/></remarks>
        public static Dictionary<bool,Dictionary<string, List<string>>> Split(int maxGroupSize, int keySize, IEnumerable<string> items)
        {
            var smallItems = from item in items
                             where item.Length < keySize
                             select item;
            var largeItems = from item in items
                             where keySize < item.Length
                             select item;
            var largeItemsq = (from item in largeItems
                               let key = item.Substring(0, keySize)
                               group item by key into x
                               select new { Key = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() } into aGrouping
                               group aGrouping by aGrouping.Items.Count() > maxGroupSize into x2
                               select x2).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.ToDictionary(a_ => a_.Key, a_ => a_.Items));
            if (smallItems.Any())
            {
                var smallestLength = items.Aggregate(int.MaxValue, (acc, item) => Math.Min(acc, item.Length));
                var smallItemsq = (from item in smallItems
                                   let key = item.Substring(0, smallestLength)
                                   group item by key into x
                                   select new { Key = x.Key, Items = x.ToList() } into aGrouping
                                   group aGrouping by aGrouping.Items.Count() > maxGroupSize into x2
                                   select x2).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.ToDictionary(a_ => a_.Key, a_ => a_.Items));
                return Combine(smallItemsq, largeItemsq);
            }
            return largeItemsq;
        }

        static Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<string,List<string>>> Combine(Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<string,List<string>>> a, Dictionary<bool, Dictionary<string,List<string>>> b) {
            var x = new Dictionary<bool,Dictionary<string,List<string>>> {
                { true, null },
                { false, null }
            };
            foreach(var condition in new bool[] { true, false }) {
                var hasA = a.ContainsKey(condition);
                var hasB = b.ContainsKey(condition);
                x[condition] = hasA && hasB ? a[condition].Concat(b[condition]).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value)
                    : hasA ? a[condition]
                    : hasB ? b[condition]
                    : new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            }
            return x;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Group(int maxGroupSize, IEnumerable<string> items, int keySize)
        {
            var toReturn = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            var both = Split(maxGroupSize, keySize, items);
            if (both.ContainsKey(false))
                foreach (var key in both[false].Keys)
                    toReturn.Add(key, both[false][key]);
            if (both.ContainsKey(true))
            {
                var keySize_ = keySize + 1;
                var xs = from needsFix in both[true]
                         select needsFix;
                foreach (var x in xs)
                {
                    var fixedGroup = Group(maxGroupSize, x.Value, keySize_);
                    toReturn = toReturn.Concat(fixedGroup).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
                }
            }
            return toReturn;
        }

        static Random rand = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks));
        const string allowedChars = "aaabbbbccccc"; // "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
        static readonly int maxAllowed = allowedChars.Length - 1;

        static IEnumerable<string> GenerateText()
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var stringLength = rand.Next(3,25);
                var chars = new List<char>(stringLength);
                for (int j = stringLength; j > 0; j--)
                    chars.Add(allowedChars[rand.Next(0, maxAllowed)]);
                var newString = chars.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, item) => acc.Append(item)).ToString();
                list.Add(newString);
            }
            return list;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // runs 1000 times over autogenerated groups of sample text.
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var s = GenerateText();
                Go(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Go(IEnumerable<string> items)
        {
            var dict = Group(3, items, 1);
            foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
                foreach (var item in dict[key])
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```